# verb used with Anstandsgefühl

Tags: collocation

Darf man hier *besitzen* als Synonym für *haben* nutzen?

> Er besitzt kein Anstandsgefühl.

Englisch:

> He has no sense of deceny.

Comment: ja, darf man. warum der Zweifel?

Comment: Weil ich kein Muttersprachler bin. Nicht alle Synonym passen genau in jeder Situation, oder? Vielleicht koennte man nicht sagen, Er vefuegt ueber kein Anstandstandgefuehle, nicht wahr?

Comment: Hier sind verschiene Varianten zulässig. Genauso möglich sind *Er hat kein Anstandsgefühl* oder *Er verfügt über kein Anstandsgefühl*.

Answer (score 1):

Man darf es nicht nur, est klingt für mich sogar natürlicher als einfach nur "hat". Kann man beides sagen und "besitzt" klingt keinesfalls künstlich oder unnatürlich.

Answer (score 1):

Man darf "besitzt" verwenden, "hat" wäre auch akzeptiert. "Er verfügt über kein Anstandsgefühl" klänge für viele sicher altertümlich